# Low Apache/mod_wsgi throughput

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

I have a trivial WSGI app running on pesto, mod_wsgi and Apache:

```
def viewData(request):
    return Response("aaaaaaaaaa" * 120000) # return 1,2MB of data
```

On my test machine, I get about 100kb/s of throughput, meaning the request takes about 12 seconds to complete. Downloading static files from the same Apache instance gives me about 20MB/s. Why is there such a huge difference, and how can I speed up the WSGI app?

Software versions: Ubuntu 10.04, Apache 2.2.14, Python 2.6.5, mod_wsgi 2.6 (all Ubuntu's default packages), pesto-18

**edit**: The real app represented by this example does not try to send static files, but dynamically produces a large amount of HTML. HTML generation happens fast (I ran it through `cProfile` and `timeit`), but the transmission is slow, and I'd like to fix that particular problem.

**edit 2**: I tested current versions of pesto (21) and mod_wsgi (3.3) on the same stack, throughput did not change significantly. I also replaced mod_wsgi with [spawning 0.9.5](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Spawning/) behind apache's mod_proxy - this increased throughput by a factor of four, but it's still miles away from what I'd like it to be.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a terribly useful test.  What are you trying to do?  At the very least, try profiling your code.  You can use the file wrapper extension (http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/FileWrapperExtension) if you want to send large static files through mod_wsgi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In WSGI the application or the framework should return an iterable. Don't know if that is what Pesto does.

Change your code to:

```
def viewData(request):
    return Response(["aaaaaaaaaa" * 120000])
```

And try again.

Comment: That did the trick. Seems like it's a little faster to iterate a one-element list than a million character string, char by char ;-)

Comment: @Simon - Don't know if it is the responsibility of the application or of the framework to wrap the response body in an iterable or if the framework should check if it isn't already wrapped and proceed to wrap it. I think you should discuss it in the Pesto list.

Comment: Although a string is an iterable and so is a valid response, as shown performance will be suck. For a WSGI middleware to detect use of common non optimal iterables, see 'http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques#Poorly_Performing_Code'. Obviously if a framework is wrapping the iterable itself and the looping is therefore in the framework, then this may not highlight issue.